# Trying to publish information from subscriber node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make system consist of several sections, it must surely have at least 1 node doing 2 roles, both subscriber and publisher. and here it my codes.

---

##First section##

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy as R
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

def sender_3():
    x = 0 
    y = float(input("Give us the float num: "))
    pub = R.Publisher("line3", Float64, queue_size=10)
    R.init_node("sender_3", anonymous=True)
    rate = R.Rate(10)
    while not R.is_shutdown() and x < y:
        x += 0.1
        t = x
        print(x)
        pub.publish(t)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        sender_3()
    except R.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

### Second section

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy as R
from std_msgs.msg import Float64, String

def callback(data):
    global r_data
    r_data = data.data
    R.loginfo("sawadee krub i've received as info: %f", data.data)
    global t_o
    t_o = str(r_data)
    R.loginfo("Applied num to chatGPT: %s", t_o)
def receiver_2():
    R.init_node("receiver_2", anonymous=10)
    R.Subscriber("line3", Float64, callback, queue_size=True)
    pub = R.Publisher("translne", String, queue_size=10)
    rate = R.Rate(10)
    while not R.is_shutdown:
        print(t_o)
        pub.publish(t_o)
        rate.sleep()
    R.spin()
#def transporter():
 #   R.init_node("transporter send you", anonymous=10)
  #  pub = R.Publisher("translne", String, queue_size=10)
   # while not R.is_shutdown:
    #    print(receiver_2)
     #   pub.publish(receiver_2)
      #  R.Rate(10)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    receiver_2()
```

---

### Last section

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy as R
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data):
    R.loginfo("I've received an information: %s", data.data)
def sub_receiver():
    R.init_node("sub_receiver", anonymous=True)
    R.Subscriber("translne", String , callback, queue_size=10)
    R.spin() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub_receiver()
```

---

My problem is during the transition between second and last section, it seems like last section didn't receive any information which is translated into String and published to last section, cause there's nothing appears even error.
P.S I commented on third section for several previous tries.
Edited: Mistakes have been fixed.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418256/trying-to-publish-information-from-subscriber-node./) by [Nongtuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/168802/nongtuy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code is not doing this correctly. Please look at section 2 of http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time for the proper way to construct a while/Rate loop in python.

```
while not R.is_shutdown:     # <- wrong
    print(t_o)
    pub.publish(t_o)
    R.Rate(10)        # <- wrong
R.spin()    #  <- wrong
```

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nongtuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/168802/nongtuy/) on 2023-08-08**:
Oh silly me, I always forget to add () in definition. After I added that it works properly now
Thank you
Best regard, Tuy